# Modification of existing binary firmware update

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware, binary

I have several IP cameras from china, and I need to add some software to it. I have to ways how to burn my software into camera ROM using hardware programmer and using special binary what I upload into camera using camera's Web interface. I decide to use special binary.

Ok, I'd download this binary from [here](http://bspsecurity.ru/download-file/proshivka-ot-25-10-2015-6.zip.). The binary successfully uploaded into camera and I decide to watch inside it. I use `binwalk` program. `binwalk` tell me next:

```
[arhichief@arhichief-pc updates]$ binwalk di20_fl_03.upw 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
152           0x98            uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x863E2566, created: 2014-08-01 04:16:33, image size: 3091196 bytes, Data Address: 0x80008000, Entry Point: 0x80008000, data CRC: 0x3B8FC9B, OS: Linux, CPU: ARM, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: none, image name: "Linux-3.0.8"
16243         0x3F73          gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, NULL date (1970-01-01 00:00:00)
3091412       0x2F2BD4        Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, compression:xz, size: 7403482 bytes, 24 inodes, blocksize: 262144 bytes, created: 2015-05-10 02:32:07
```

The `file` command told me, what it is a binary image of ROM:

```
[arhichief@arhichief-pc updates]$ file di20_fl_03.upw 
di20_fl_03.upw: UNIF v-740431636 format NES ROM image
```

After extracting the parts of binary, I found that data after 0x2F2BD4 is an image of the storage with additional software and bash script to run it. Looks like, I found the way how to insert my software into camera.

Using `dd`, I get this part of binary, extract it, add my programs, pack it back and write back into binary file.

```
[arhichief@arhichief-pc updates]$ dd conv=notrunc bs=1 if=di20_fl_03.upw skip=3091412 count=7403482 of=fs.sqhsfs
7403482+0 records in
7403482+0 records out
7403482 bytes (7.4 MB, 7.1 MiB) copied, 8.7586 s, 845 kB/s

[arhichief@arhichief-pc updates]$ unsquashfs fs.sqhsfs 
Parallel unsquashfs: Using 4 processors
23 inodes (72 blocks) to write

[=================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================|] 72/72 100%

created 23 files
created 1 directories
created 0 symlinks
created 0 devices
created 0 fifos
[arhichief@arhichief-pc updates]$ cd squashfs-root/
[arhichief@arhichief-pc squashfs-root]$ dd if=/dev/random bs=1 of=TEST.FILE count=1258291
^C234+0 records in
234+0 records out
234 bytes copied, 28.535 s, 0.0 kB/s

[arhichief@arhichief-pc updates]$ mksquashfs squashfs-root/ fs.sqhsfs -comp xz -Xdict-size 100% -b 262144
Parallel mksquashfs: Using 4 processors
Creating 4.0 filesystem on fs.sqhsfs, block size 262144.
[=================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================|] 78/78 100%

Exportable Squashfs 4.0 filesystem, xz compressed, data block size 262144
    compressed data, compressed metadata, compressed fragments, compressed xattrs
    duplicates are removed
Filesystem size 8529.98 Kbytes (8.33 Mbytes)
    56.79% of uncompressed filesystem size (15020.30 Kbytes)
Inode table size 494 bytes (0.48 Kbytes)
    47.23% of uncompressed inode table size (1046 bytes)
Directory table size 374 bytes (0.37 Kbytes)
    87.59% of uncompressed directory table size (427 bytes)
Number of duplicate files found 0
Number of inodes 25
Number of files 24
Number of fragments 3
Number of symbolic links  0
Number of device nodes 0
Number of fifo nodes 0
Number of socket nodes 0
Number of directories 1
Number of ids (unique uids + gids) 2
Number of uids 1
    arhichief (1000)
Number of gids 1
    users (100)

[arhichief@arhichief-pc updates]$ dd if=fs.sqhsfs of=di20_fl_03_new.upw conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=3091412
8736768+0 records in
8736768+0 records out
8736768 bytes (8.7 MB, 8.3 MiB) copied, 8.81158 s, 992 kB/s
```

After what I match new firmware update binary with `binwalk` to make sure, everything is ok.

```
[arhichief@arhichief-pc updates]$ binwalk di20_fl_03_new.upw 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
152           0x98            uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x863E2566, created: 2014-08-01 04:16:33, image size: 3091196 bytes, Data Address: 0x80008000, Entry Point: 0x80008000, data CRC: 0x3B8FC9B, OS: Linux, CPU: ARM, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: none, image name: "Linux-3.0.8"
16243         0x3F73          gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, NULL date (1970-01-01 00:00:00)
3091412       0x2F2BD4        Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, compression:xz, size: 8734702 bytes, 25 inodes, blocksize: 262144 bytes, created: 2016-06-06 07:46:09
```

I try to upload new firmware update binary into the camera, but camera return me an error.

Ok. I'd try to search for some solutions and found [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8019/hikvision-camera-firmware-reverse-engineering). From answers in that thread I get a python script what extract firmware and shows the checksums of firmware parts. Good. This script show me next:

```
[arhichief@arhichief-pc updates]$ python2 extract_hikvision_dav_file.py di20_fl_03.upw 
Magic number:    5a4b5356
Header checksum: 0000223a
Header length:   00000098
File number:     00000002
Language:        00000001
Device class:    00000002
Calced checksum: 0000223a
75496d6167650000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000980000003c2b2f001d4e7b18
File name:          uImage
Start:              00000098
Length:             002f2b3c
Checksum:           187b4e1d
Calced checksum:    187b4e1d
6170702e696d6700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d42b2f00000071003d7de138
File name:          app.img
Start:              002f2bd4
Length:             00710000
Checksum:           38e17d3d
Calced checksum:    38e17d3d

[arhichief@arhichief-pc updates]$ python2 extract_hikvision_dav_file.py di20_fl_03_new.upw 
Magic number:    5a4b5356
Header checksum: 0000223a
Header length:   00000098
File number:     00000002
Language:        00000001
Device class:    00000002
Calced checksum: 0000223a
75496d6167650000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000980000003c2b2f001d4e7b18
File name:          uImage
Start:              00000098
Length:             002f2b3c
Checksum:           187b4e1d
Calced checksum:    187b4e1d
6170702e696d6700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d42b2f00000071003d7de138
File name:          app.img
Start:              002f2bd4
Length:             00710000
Checksum:           38e17d3d
Calced checksum:    38754ea4
```

I found that checksums in default and updated firmwares are mismatch. I have some experience in C, so, I decide to rewrite python script in C and modify it so it will correct checksums. Here is my [code](http://pastebin.com/bV9rL2P6). So, It works well, I think. The results of python script and my code are same after my code patch checksums. But when I try to upload firmware with corrected checksums into camera, it still return error.

I don't know what I shall do next, and I think you will give me some advices.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Please, sorry for long question. I think you will need to know all my steps to give me correct answer. I think I've made an error some there in it.

Comment: Reverse engineer the updater program which consumes firmware update binaries on the camera; find out which check doesn't pass. Post your findings as the answer here.

Comment: Thanks for response. Maybe there is a an information about how to get this binary file structure?

Comment: download link is dead